# Retrieving variable name in order to print them in specman

Tags: specman

I wish to do the following in Specman:

```
my_task() is {
   var my_var : int;
   my_var = 5;

   message(LOW,appendf("%s=[%d]",my_var.to_name(),my_var));

};
```

Currently, I'm in search of the internal task `to_name()`. I do not want to create a struct for this. I wish to only use Specman internals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you'd do this unless you somehow have the collection of all the fields, which would give you the *name* of all the fields.

So, I'm going to branch predict and assume that you want all the *fields* of a given `struct/unit`:

```
extend sys {

    A : list of uint;
    B : int;
    cee : string;
    run() is also {

        var rf_sys: rf_struct = rf_manager.get_exact_subtype_of_instance(sys);
        for each (field) in rf_sys.get_declared_fields() {
             print field;
             print field.get_long_name();  // <-- Here's your "get_name()" function
          };
    };
};
```

On version 8.2, this yields:

```
Usage: . env.sh [-32bit|-64bit] [-v] [[VAR=value]...]
Welcome to Specman Elite(64) (09.20.482-d)  -  Linked on Wed Mar  2 13:32:19
2011

Protected by U.S. Patents 6,141,630 ;6,182,258; 6,219,809; 6,347,388;
6,487,704; 6,499,132; 6,502,232; 6,519,727; 6,530,054; 6,675,138; 6,684,359;
6,687,662; 6,907,599; 6,918,076; 6,920,583; Other Patents Pending.

1 notification was modified by command 'set notify -severity=WARNING
DEPR_START_TCM_ARG_BY_REF'
Checking license ... OK
Loading /nfs/pdx/home/rbroger1/tmp.e ...
read...parse...update...patch...h code...code...clean...GC(sys)...

Doing setup ...
Generating the test using seed 1...

Starting the test ...
Running the test ...
  field = rf_field 'time', Specman's private modules
  field.get_long_name() = "time"
  field = rf_field 'logger', Specman's private modules
  field.get_long_name() = "logger"
  field = rf_field 'A', line 5 in @tmp
  field.get_long_name() = "A"
  field = rf_field 'B', line 6 in @tmp
  field.get_long_name() = "B"
  field = rf_field 'cee', line 7 in @tmp
  field.get_long_name() = "cee"
No actual running requested.
Checking the test ...
Checking is complete - 0 DUT errors, 0 DUT warnings.
```

If that doesn't quite answer your question, look more into Specman's introspection or reflection interface in the documentation for your version of Specman.  Warning, details are a bit scarce from Cadence.  Also, [see my answer to "Specman: how to retrieve values of var which is stored in another var".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331627/specman-how-to-retrieve-values-of-var-which-is-stored-in-another-var/3338870#3338870).  Finally, in `specview` you can use the data browser to browse the `rf_manger` *itself* ( introspection at its best).  Then you can find all the functions that Cadence *doesn't* tell you about in their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the string name of a variable. Although you can get the name of a field using `get_name()`.

This makes some sense, because the variable is only known at the location it is declared. You can't even access the variable in a later extension of `my_task()`. So if you are already editing the code at the location where the variable was declared, just say `"my_var"` rather than `my_var.to_name()`. (Yes, typos and cut and paste errors can happen.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
define <dump'action> "dump <exp>" as {
    out("<exp>","=[",<exp>,"]");
};
```

you can use this macro in the specman command line or inside functions, for example:

```
foo() is {
    var a : int = 5;
    dump a;
};
```

will give:

```
a=[5]
```